# How to get complete user profile using ADAL services in angular 2

Tags: angular, azure, angular2-forms, adal

Currently i'm using ADAL service to fetch user information from azure AD, but i'm getting all the fields except PS number field. It is a default field added by administrator and he is able to view that filed in response from powershell, but when i try to fetch response using ADAL service i m not getting that field. following is the code i have implemented.

```
 if(this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated){
            this.loginName=this.adalService.userInfo.profile.name;
       //code to set current login value to global var
           this.loginData.globalLoginMailID=this.adalService.userInfo.profile.upn;
           this.loginData.globalLoginName=this.loginName;
           this.globalVarsProviderObj.setMyLogin(this.loginData);  
}
```

Comment: What is the PS number? Is it an extension attribute? If it is, then you can fetch it from the Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph. I am not sure if it is possible to include it in the id token (claims customization is in preview, not sure if you can do this with that).

Comment: PS number is a default attribute. And if i use Graph API then i need to generate bearer token which is not possible at run time as it expires.